# Invalid Date in moment.js datetime addition

Tags: momentjs

I want to add time/duration in HH:mm(eg 00:10) to a Date time in format MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM

I have date and time in 2 separate objects so am trying the below

```
  var plannedStartDate = document.getElementById("date1"); //eg 02-12-2020
  var plannedStartTime = document.getElementById("plannedStart1"); //eg 09:00

  var plannedStartDateTime = moment(plannedStartDate.value + " " + plannedStartTime.value);

  var minutes = $("#duration1").text().split(':')[1];
  var hours = $("#duration1").text().split(':')[0];

  var date = plannedStartDateTime.add(hours, 'hours').add(minutes, 'minutes').format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm");

  console.log("Final:"+date); //gives invalid date
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Check this working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2

It adds the hours and minutes to the input date and then prints in a given format

```
var moment = require("moment");
var input = "2020-02-12";
var hoursMinutes = "9:10";
var hours = hoursMinutes.split(":")[0];
var minutes = hoursMinutes.split(":")[1];
var momentInTime = moment(input)
  .add(hours, "hours")
  .add(minutes, "minutes");
var converted = moment(momentInTime).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
console.log(converted);
```